# Point existing domain to new hosting that has temporary domain and make it the primary domain

Tags: dns, migration, hosting, web-hosting

How would I take an existing domain and point it to a new website on a different server?

Specifically:
I have a website currently, lets call it `www.example.com` hosted on an old hosting company. This website is going to go away entirely and be replaced with a new one. The new website is being built and currently hosted on `www.example.org` (notice the .org). The domain is registered with GoDaddy so I changed the nameservers to point to my HostGator VPS hosting plan that has 2 dedicated IP addresses.

Is this as simple as pointing the nameservers for `www.example.com` to the nameservers on my new hosting with HostGator? I am getting confused with the way that hostgator has a "Primary Domain" currently set to `www.example.org` but eventually will need to be `www.example.com`.

Comment: In order to host your domain with HG, you just need to point your domain to HG name server. Your DNS will automatically resolve within 12-24 hours.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this on Webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

1. It will not cause any issue if the primary domain is set to `example.org`.

You will have to add the current domain (`example.com`) to the service with HostGator and upload the site content in the domain's root directory (`example.com`).

Once the content is uploaded properly, you will have to change the nameserver of your current domain (`example.com`) to point it to the new server.

2. The simplest way is.

You can contact your hosting provider to change the primary domain to `example.com`. Then you will have to change your domain's name servers to point it to the new hosting service.